# iphone test tool for uiwebview

Tags: iphone

I'm looking for a iphone test tool which has big support for uiwebview. Because I'm making a hybrid app, basically make a native shell and render a website inside the uiwebview of my app. I need a tool to help me test the user interaction with the website. So when the other people change the website, they can run this test first to make sure their changes don't screw my stuff. I checked couple of popular iphone test tools, they don't have a good support on uiwebview. Is there any recommendation? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fonemonkey has inbuilt support for selenium, if you can write a selenium script for your hybrid web app and use fonemonkey to run them i guess it is quite possible to do the testing.

hey one more thing, fonemonkey is now replaced with monkey talk, try that out, 
http://www.360logica.com/360logica-social/blog/item/123-monkey-talk-for-ios-set-up

monkey talk website: http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk